# How to throw an Error explicitly while processing Mono

Tags: java, exception, project-reactor

I need to know how to throw an exception explicitly while executing the Mono. I'm not able to subscribe, block Mono because it has end (down-stream) subscriber. Just need to validate the data and throw exception explicitly to perform retry.

```
    public Mono<Response> handleResponse() {
        return userService.getUser()
                .doOnNext(response -> validate(response.getData()))
                .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                    // not working
                    throw Exceptions.propagete(ex);
                });
    }
    
    private void validate() {
        .....
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

```
@Retyable(value = {RuntimeException.class})
```

If no exception, it will return Mono to next level. I can use Mono retry itself but need to know is there any way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

To produce an error you can use `Mono.error(throwable)`.

But the another problem in your code that you do the validation in `doOnNext`, which is not supposed to change the flow. Better to use `flatMap`.

You can do something like:

```
userService.getUser()
            .flatMap(response -> {
               try {
                  validate(response.getData());
                  return Mono.just(response);
               } catch (Throwable t) {
                  return Mono.error(t);
               }
            })
```

Comment: This is not working. Exception occurred within Mono itself. Only subscribers will be notified, can't explicitly throw or catch the exception.

Comment: @Mihan, but this is expected and this is how a reactor works. If you want to throw an exception out of the Mono scope, you should block your chain (that's not recommended). If you want to retry your code in case of RuntimeException in a reactive way just use in your chain the following operator: `.retryWhen(Retry.max(3).filter(e -> e instanceof RuntimeException))` (it has flexible configurations).

Comment: @YevheniiSemenov yes that is correct. i already know that solution. My question is if any occurs no point of staying on mono scope. Just leave the scope and let spring to do the retry.  I can't block the scope because it has next level subscriber and if any exception not throwed next level subscriber need to get the Mono.

Comment: @Mihan I'm afraid it cannot be done because the reactor was not designed to function this way.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be the following:

```java
getUser()
    .map(response -> {
        validate(response);
        return response;
    })
```

If it's possible for you to make changes to the `validate` method, I would suggest doing it in the following manner:

```java
getUser()
    .handle((response, sink) -> {
        if (isValid(response)) {
            sink.next(response);
        } else {
            sink.error(new RuntimeException("..."));
        }
    })

// where
public boolean isValid(User user) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try something like this:

```java
    public Mono<Response> handleResponse() {
            return Mono.fromFuture(userService.getUser()
                    .doOnNext(response -> validate(response.getData()))
                    .handle((response, throwable) -> {
                          if (throwable == null) {
                              return response;
                          } else {
                              throw new RuntimeException();
                          }
                     });
    }
```